# google authenticator with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Are there any sample implementation for google authenticator as two factor authentication implementation in addition to sms and email?

Found one sample.
[Sample Google Authenticator using asp.net](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-google-authenticator-asp-net-identity/)

But there are lots of changes while using it with asp.net core.

Comment: I found this post quite helpful: https://chsakell.com/2019/08/18/asp-net-core-identity-series-two-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 8):

You can use AspNetCore.Totp.
https://github.com/damirkusar/AspNetCore.Totp

It works exactly like GoogleAuthenticator, have a look at the Tests project for the implementation (really simple).

You just have a couple of lines to write to get the qurcode and to validate the pin code:

```
using AspNetCore.Totp;

...

// To generate the qrcode/setup key

var totpSetupGenerator = new TotpSetupGenerator();
var totpSetup = totpSetupGenerator.Generate("You app name here", "The username", "YourSuperSecretKeyHere", 300, 300);
                                                    
string qrCodeImageUrl = totpSetup.QrCodeImage;
string manualEntrySetupCode = totpSetup.ManualSetupKey;


// To validate the pin after user input (where pin is an int variable)
var totpGenerator = new TotpGenerator();
var totpValidator = new TotpValidator(totpGenerator);
bool isCorrectPIN = totpValidator.Validate("YourSuperSecretKeyHere", pin);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. The manual setup key works, but the QR code does not. I got very long string of QR code like more than 2000 characters that could not interpret in the browser. The QR code string looks like : ""data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU....". Do you know any way to decode it into simple QR code?

Comment: That string is the image data in base64 format. To display it in a browser, have the string show in a `<img>` tag like so: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU....">`